# how to pass chunk of audio files to Mozilla DeepSpeech web socket?

Tags: django, speech-recognition, mozilla-deepspeech

when a live speech is going on, I want to separate it into a chunk of short mp3 files and send it to a Mozilla DeepSpeech WebSocket for transcribing

(speech is conducted using the device microphone)